# For loop in R for extracting text from png files

Tags: r, regex, ocr, tesseract

I have some .png files in the folder, I need to read them all one by one, and concatenate the text generated from all the files i a single variable. I am using the below code:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/tmpxk9/Documents", pattern="*.png")

for (i in seq_along(filenames)) {
  xx <- magick::image_read("filenames[i]")
  xx %>%
    magick::image_resize("2000x") %>%
    magick::image_convert(type = 'Grayscale') %>%
    tesseract::ocr() %>%
    cat()
}
```

It errors out with the following error:

```
Error in magick_image_readpath(enc2native(path), density, depth, strip) : 
  rsession.exe: UnableToOpenBlob `C:\Users\tmpxk9\Documents\filenames[i]': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701
```

I am sure there is some issue with for loop, I am working on it, but not able to figure out

Comment: Hard to explore further without a reproducible example, but for starters, "filenames[i]" should not be a string in quotes. Should be: `xx <- magick::image_read(filenames[i])`

Comment: quotation mark is the issue. now its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are retrieving the file names, they are not including the folder they are stored in. In order to get the full paths with `list.files()`, you have to include the argument `full.names = TRUE`.